# Use Integrated Graphics for WiDi and Discrete Graphics card for monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics

I have a GForce GTX 480 (old I know) running my 2 monitors, and I'd like to use the HD4600 Integrated Graphics from my i7-4790 to mirror my main display via WiDi to my TV.

The Miracast receiver part works perfectly fine (my laptop connects flawlessly) but my desktop doesn't give me the option to connect to a wireless display.  I know that it is my graphics card that is the issue (I'm using the Wireless AC-7260 for Desktop card), and I know that the HD4600 supports WiDi.  My motherboard is the GA-Z97X-UD5H if that is important

Is there any way to use the Integrated Graphics card mirror my display via WiDi?

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you want and use the dGPU to output to two monitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by plugging in one of my monitors into the integrated graphics port and by making the IGX the primary display in my UEFI.